# How to depend on the sources of another project

Tags: scala, sbt, scala.js

I have two projects that use scalajs where the second project needs access to the sources of the first. I define my first project.sbt something like the following:

```
val commonSettings = Seq(
    name := "project1",
    unmanagedSourceDirectories in Compile +=
        baseDirectory.value / ".." / "shared" / "src" / "main" / "scala",
)

val project1JS = project.in(file("js"))
    .settings(commonSettings: _*)
    .enablePlugins(ScalaJSPlugin)


val project1JVM = project.in(file("jvm"))
    .settings(commonSettings: _*)
```

In order for project 2 to have access to the sources of project 1 I define its sbt as follows:

```
val commonSettings = Seq(
    name := "project2",
    unmanagedSourceDirectories in Compile +=
        baseDirectory.value / ".." / "shared" / "src" / "main" / "scala",
)

val project2JS = project.in(file("js"))
    .settings(commonSettings: _*)
    .configure(_.dependsOn(ProjectRef(uri("../project1"), "project1JS")))
    .enablePlugins(ScalaJSPlugin)

val project2JVM = project.in(file("jvm"))
    .settings(commonSettings: _*)
    .configure(_.dependsOn(ProjectRef(uri("../project1"), "project1JVM")))
```

My second project compiles fine but this raises a problem in that I now have access to project1's classpath which can cause conflicts. For example I am getting warnings that more than one logback.xml file has been found and the incorrect application.conf file can also be picked up.

Is there a better way of depending on the sources for project1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best alternative solution I could come up with was to add unmanagedSourceDirectories settings to my second project. So for example by doing:

```
val project2JVM = project.in(file("jvm"))
    .settings(commonSettings: _*)
    .settings(
        unmanagedSourceDirectories in Compile +=
            baseDirectory.value / ".." / ".." / "project1" / "shared" / "src" / "main" / "scala",
    )
```

Project2 now has access to the shared sources in Project1 without access to the resources for Project1 on its classpath